# Как отключить анимацию определенного слайда?

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени, у меня есть  [сайт](http://idealdom.kz/)

Мне нужно отключить анимацию определенного слайда, но я не знаю какой файл этим всем управляет, как мне выбрать id="bonus" и остановить все анимации только на нем?

```
<div class="slider">                                 
<ul class="items">   
  <li id="bonus"><img title="Вкусный бонус от Docke" alt="Вкусный бонус от Docke" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/slideBonus.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Розыгрыш смартфона от компании Идеальный Dom" alt="s7 edge розыгрыш" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/galaxy-s7-edge-ux-660x330.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b> 
          <h1>ВЫЙГРАЙ СМАРТФОН</h1>
         </b> 
        <p>Принимай участие в розыгрыше смартфона Galaxy S7 и Galaxy S7 Edge. Пройди моментальную <a href="#" onclick="jivo_config.chat_mode = 'offline';jivo_config.offline_form_text = 'Для участия в розыгрыше заполните поля, с кодовым словом galaxy';jivo_config.offline_widget_label = 'Регистрация';jivo_init();setTimeout(function(){jivo_api.open();},2500);" >регистрацию в нашем чате</a> и удача обязательно улыбнется тебе.</p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="фасадные панели + софиты + водостоки Дёке + гибкая битумная черепица " alt="сочетание софитов, фасадных панелей, водосточной системы и гибкой черепицы Дёке" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images//slide-1.png"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b> 
          <h1>ИДЕАЛЬНЫЙ ДОМ № 1</h1>
         </b> 
        <p>В данном примере : Кровельная часть исполнена <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/gbch_docke.php" title="ГБЧ Дёке" >гибкой битумной черепицей Docke</a>, фасадная часть облицована <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/fasadnye_paneli_docke.php" title="Фасадные панели Docke-r" >панелями Docke-r</a>, карнизы украшают <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/sofity.php" title="Соффиты Дёке" >соффиты - Docke</a>, водосточная система - <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/vodostoki_docke.php" title="Водосточная система Дёке" >Docke standart</a>.</p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Вкусный бонус от Docke" alt="Вкусный бонус от Docke" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/slideBonus.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Розыгрыш смартфона от компании Идеальный Dom" alt="s7 edge розыгрыш" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/galaxy-s7-edge-ux-660x330.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b> 
          <h1>ВЫЙГРАЙ СМАРТФОН</h1>
         </b> 
        <p>Принимай участие в розыгрыше смартфона Galaxy S7 и Galaxy S7 Edge. Пройди моментальную <a href="#" onclick="jivo_config.chat_mode = 'offline';jivo_config.offline_form_text = 'Для участия в розыгрыше заполните поля, с кодовым словом galaxy';jivo_config.offline_widget_label = 'Регистрация';jivo_init();setTimeout(function(){jivo_api.open();},2500);" >регистрацию в нашем чате</a> и удача обязательно улыбнется тебе.</p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="профнастил + металлосайдинг + водосточка ИНСИ" alt="сочетание профлиста с металлосайдингом и металлической водосточной системой" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images//slide-2.png"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                  <b>ИДЕАЛЬНЫЙ ДОМ № 2</b> 
        <br />

        <p>В данном примере : Кровельная часть исполнена <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/faltsevaya_krovlya.php" title="Фальцевая кровля ИНСИ" >фальцевой кровлей ИНСИ</a>, фасадная часть облицована <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/saiding_insi.php" title="Металлический сайдинг ИНСИ" >металлосайдингом ИНСИ</a>, для отвода талых и дождевых вод, установлена металлическая <a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/vodostoki_insi.php" >водосточная система       - ИНСИ</a>.         </p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Вкусный бонус от Docke" alt="Вкусный бонус от Docke" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/slideBonus.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Розыгрыш смартфона от компании Идеальный Dom" alt="s7 edge розыгрыш" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/galaxy-s7-edge-ux-660x330.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b> 
          <h1>ВЫЙГРАЙ СМАРТФОН</h1>
         </b> 
        <p>Принимай участие в розыгрыше смартфона Galaxy S7 и Galaxy S7 Edge. Пройди моментальную <a href="#" onclick="jivo_config.chat_mode = 'offline';jivo_config.offline_form_text = 'Для участия в розыгрыше заполните поля, с кодовым словом galaxy';jivo_config.offline_widget_label = 'Регистрация';jivo_init();setTimeout(function(){jivo_api.open();},2500);" >регистрацию в нашем чате</a> и удача обязательно улыбнется тебе.</p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="сайдинг + ГБЧ Дёке" alt="сочетание черепицы Дёке с виниловым сайдингом" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images//slide-3.png"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b>ИДЕАЛЬНЫЙ ДОМ № 3</b> 
        <p>В данном примере : Кровельная часть исполнена <font size="2"><a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/gbch_docke.php" title="Гибкая битумная черепица" >гибкой черепицей Docke</a>, фасадная часть облицована </font><a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/saiding_docke.php" title="Сайдинг ПВХ" >виниловым сайдингом</a><font size="2"> Docke. </font></p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Вкусный бонус от Docke" alt="Вкусный бонус от Docke" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/slideBonus.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Розыгрыш смартфона от компании Идеальный Dom" alt="s7 edge розыгрыш" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/galaxy-s7-edge-ux-660x330.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b> 
          <h1>ВЫЙГРАЙ СМАРТФОН</h1>
         </b> 
        <p>Принимай участие в розыгрыше смартфона Galaxy S7 и Galaxy S7 Edge. Пройди моментальную <a href="#" onclick="jivo_config.chat_mode = 'offline';jivo_config.offline_form_text = 'Для участия в розыгрыше заполните поля, с кодовым словом galaxy';jivo_config.offline_widget_label = 'Регистрация';jivo_init();setTimeout(function(){jivo_api.open();},2500);" >регистрацию в нашем чате</a> и удача обязательно улыбнется тебе.</p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="сайдинг + ондулин" alt="сочетание сайдинга Дёке с ондулином" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images//slide-4.png"  /> 
    <div class="banner"><span>                                   <b>ИДЕАЛЬНЫЙ ДОМ № 4</b> 
        <p>В данном примере : Кровельная часть исполнена легкой кровлей <font size="2"><a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/onduline.php" title="Кровля ондулин" >ондулин</a>, фасадная часть облицована </font><a href="http://idealdom.kz/products/saiding_docke.php" title="Сайдинг ПВХ" >виниловым сайдингом</a><font size="2"> Docke - корабельный брус </font></p>
                                        </span></div>
   </li>

  <li><img title="Вкусный бонус от Docke" alt="Вкусный бонус от Docke" src="http://idealdom.kz/bitrix/templates/idealdom/images/slideBonus.jpg"  /> 
    <div class="banner"></div>
   </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                            <a href="#" class="prev" >&lt;</a> <a href="#" class="play" ><em>stop</em><span>play</span></a> <a href="#" class="next" >&gt;</a>
```

Comment: Для поиска управляющего файла сохраните на компьютер весь сайт, далее при помощи total commander воспользуйтесь поиском по файлам, которые содержат текст, например в данном случаем можете поискать по <li id="bonus">, таким образом вы найдете отвечающий за слайдер файл.